# Minimum Requirements of ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: system-requirements

I want to install ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my computer. But I am a little worried about system requirements. I can find 'Recommended' System Requirements on ubuntu website. But I am unaware of 'Minimum System Requirements' as they have been discontinued for publishing on the ubuntu website after the release of version 12. I have 512MB of RAM, 1GHz Processor and 8 GB of storage. I doubt that I might be able to run it as I saw my friend running version 16 on a age-old computer a few months back. Would I be able to run ubuntu on my system. I don't want to try any other OS or Linux disro.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe you will be able to run Desktop version of Ubuntu as those are minimum specs:

2 GHz dual core processor
2 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

However you may be able to run server version (no GUI)

300 MHz x86 processor
256 MiB of system memory (RAM)
1.5 GB of disk space